# Save GeoJSON file in GCS

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson

I'm trying to make sure that my geojson file saved from QGIS is saved in a GCS with lat lng points. When I open my file I get coordinates like this which seems like my file is saved in nad83 as desired. However when I look at the multipolygon coords there are the numbers like `-953041.978119671810418, -905958.499384404625744` which seem like projected values to me.

My desired outcome is to have a series of shapes with the coords depicted as `[-122.51953124999999, 49.38237278700955]`.

Can anyone provide insight as to how to do this?

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": 
"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": 3524, "VertexCou": 318.0, "ISO": "USA", "NAME_0": "United States of America", "NAME_1": "New Mexico", "VARNAME_1": "NM|N.M.", "NL_NAME_1": null, "HASC_1": "US.NM", "TYPE_1": "State", "ENGTYPE_1": "State", "VALIDFR_1": "18630224", "VALIDTO_1": "Present", "REMARKS_1": null, "Region": null, "RegionVar": null, "ProvNumber": 0, "NEV_Countr": null, "FIRST_FIPS": null, "FIRST_HASC": null, "FIPS_1": "US35", "gadm_level": 1.0, "CheckMe": 0, "Region_Cod": "West", "Region_C_1": "Mountain", "ScaleRank": 0, "Region_C_2": "West", "Region_C_3": "Mountain", "Country_Pr": null, "DataRank": 1, "Abbrev": "N.M.", "Postal": "NM", "Area_sqkm": 315064.8, "sameAsCity": -99, "ADM0_A3": "USA", "MAP_COLOR": 1, "LabelRank": 0, "Shape_Leng": 23.6835943355, "Shape_Area": 30.907449186600001 }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -953041.978119671810418, -905958.499384404625744 ], [ -948363.817674559541047, -912649.658803645172156 ], [ -949415.118971111718565, -911221.965385127114132 ], [ -950373.386825972120278, -910699.221883034333587 ], [ -954129.409030217560939, -910274.234215423930436 ], [ -956457.999317199923098, -910013.450592633686028 ], [ -958782.739961177343503, -909738.206252749776468 ], [ -961110.23246107250452, -909467.709480636403896 ], [ -963439.845239550457336, -909196.329377638176084 ], [ -965764.988492790027522, -908924.810536385979503 ], [ -968092.571185612352565, -908655.222425152431242 ], [ -970420.07867271406576, -908384.999199496814981 ], [ -972747.51068811735604, -908114.14078598562628 ], [ -975072.027571407146752, -907837.270666371681727 ], [ -977401.502992079011165, -907564.890869535738602 ], [ -979729.029607222648337, -907294.940747989225201 ], [ -982053.637558469548821, -907018.981254656682722 ], [ -984380.363819797174074, -906742.134419950773008 ], [ -986707.33769754646346, -906467.466122243087739 ], [ -989036.756981094484217, -906194.721313137793913 ], [ -991362.923946594120935, -905913.155850317445584 ], [ -993689.338765343418345, -905633.768797523109242 ], [ -996018.19911565433722, -905356.303505811258219 ], [ -998345.115974471904337, -905081.272042682743631 ], [ -1000671.296444238512777, -904799.979781449539587 ], [ -1002997.397827217821032, -904518.052874623099342 ], [ -1005321.556313939159736, -904238.562664008233696 ], [ -1007650.027317312546074, -903957.919871989055537 ], [ -1009973.696462118183263, -903674.34870797698386 ], [ -1012299.481002866989002, -903389.883483292651363 ], [ -1014625.520272630266845, -903107.595777398673818 ], [ -1016951.816345254075713, -902827.485556295607239 ], [ -1019275.167722485377453, -902541.378739018808119 ], [ -1021602.828142913756892, -902254.112260204274207 ], [ -1023928.213027013349347, -901966.473844578140415 ], [ -1026250.983693397953175, -901675.653320114826784 ], [ -1028576.545268095564097, -901389.5581842957763 ], [ -1030902.36729293607641, -901105.640106575679965 ], [ -1033225.234655434149317, -900815.730278274742886 ], [ -1035550.214923190418631, -900524.920419256668538 ], [ -1037875.113426683587022, -900233.476261497242376 ], [ -1040201.780797366285697, -899938.318504951079376 ], [ -1042524.66430466179736, -899648.684633772121742 ], [ -1044854.393950503319502, -899360.4213408511132 ], [ -1047176.771083631319925, -899066.7081034546718 ], [ -1049499.065632221987471, -898772.361681860988028 ], [ -1051830.399815081851557, -898479.10952267923858 ], [ -1054153.225009687012061, -898189.115957197616808 ], [ -1056477.118135730503127, -897889.785058433772065 ], [ -1058801.275762177770957, -897592.630640245508403 ], [ -1061125.699950024951249, -897297.652555599925108 ], [ -1063450.392976713366807, -897004.850418474641629 ], [ -1065774.301861634012312, -896705.793271167785861 ], [ -1068098.126732295146212, -896406.102126024896279 ], [ -1070422.220515142660588, -896108.586818729527295 ], [ -1072744.392448414582759, -895813.52353970927652 ], [ -1075067.966578460531309, -895511.930542250513099
```

Comment: How do you set the CRS for your layer?

Comment: Save layer as in QGIS then define the CRS in the save vector layer as modal

Comment: Perhaps I need to reproject project before saving?

Comment: Interesting, the Coordinates in the bottom left of the screen are the same as being saved, so I need to change those into a standard lat lng. Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I had to export the file as a kml, which inexplicably transformed all the coords which looked like eastings and northings into lat lngs.

Then convert that kml to geojson using an online converter, but it looked like you could also do that using ogr.

I'd be very interested to know why I couldn't export those features as lat lngs via a geojson? Is this a bug or expected behavior?

kml of the same file came out like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Schema name="na_provinces" id="na_provinces">
    <SimpleField name="OBJECTID" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="VertexCou" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ISO" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NAME_0" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NAME_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="VARNAME_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NL_NAME_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="HASC_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="TYPE_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ENGTYPE_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="VALIDFR_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="VALIDTO_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="REMARKS_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Region" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="RegionVar" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ProvNumber" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="NEV_Countr" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="FIRST_FIPS" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="FIRST_HASC" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="FIPS_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="gadm_level" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="CheckMe" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Region_Cod" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Region_C_1" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ScaleRank" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Region_C_2" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Region_C_3" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Country_Pr" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="DataRank" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Abbrev" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Postal" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Area_sqkm" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="sameAsCity" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="ADM0_A3" type="string"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="MAP_COLOR" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="LabelRank" type="int"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Shape_Leng" type="float"></SimpleField>
    <SimpleField name="Shape_Area" type="float"></SimpleField>
</Schema>
<Folder><name>na_provinces</name>
  <Placemark>
    <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
    <ExtendedData><SchemaData schemaUrl="#na_provinces">
        <SimpleData name="OBJECTID">3524</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="VertexCou">318</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ISO">USA</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME_0">United States of America</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="NAME_1">New Mexico</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="VARNAME_1">NM|N.M.</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="HASC_1">US.NM</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="TYPE_1">State</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ENGTYPE_1">State</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="VALIDFR_1">18630224</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="VALIDTO_1">Present</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ProvNumber">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="FIPS_1">US35</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="gadm_level">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="CheckMe">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Region_Cod">West</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Region_C_1">Mountain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ScaleRank">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Region_C_2">West</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Region_C_3">Mountain</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="DataRank">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Abbrev">N.M.</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Postal">NM</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Area_sqkm">315064.8</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="sameAsCity">-99</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="ADM0_A3">USA</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="MAP_COLOR">1</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="LabelRank">0</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Leng">23.6835943355</SimpleData>
        <SimpleData name="Shape_Area">30.9074491866</SimpleData>
    </SchemaData></ExtendedData>
      <MultiGeometry><Polygon><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-136.073935405723,-7.98485762423114 -136.034499007388,-8.04514134193714 -136.043383449391,-8.03226215911465 -136.051704241354,-8.0273831338576 -136.084779915201,-8.02256644454604 -136.105283780235,-8.01960323299384 -136.125747510132,-8.01651317137938 -136.146234952091,-8.01346356927489 -136.16673889981,-8.01040500931291 -136.187201346925,-8.0073459437603 -136.207683926041,-8.00430261103881 -136.228163679344,-8.0012531407571 -136.248640601718,-7.99819753512626 -136.269088056935,-7.99508929040288 -136.289578612427,-7.99201858357136 -136.310050675617,-7.98896926481038 -136.330493235967,-7.98586734731968 -136.350952245864,-7.98275645861469 -136.371412078714,-7.9796641191537 -136.391892056164,-7.9765874421118 -136.412338753141,-7.97343356194371 -136.432786267661,-7.97029823607087 -136.45325391423,-7.96717856207301 -136.473703115081,-7.96408032006254 -136.494141973424,-7.96092669233326 -136.514577932572,-7.95776697606617 -136.534995454145,-7.95462872564255 -136.555448653337,-7.95147854697434 -136.575856620927,-7.94830350515559 -136.596280955444,-7.94511946168034 -136.616706150658,-7.94195396363663 -136.63713222401,-7.93880700621873 -136.65752853591,-7.93560769483715 -136.677960452613,-7.93239640965503 -136.698370162603,-7.92918201815577 -136.7187538505,-7.92593993517815 -136.739161493869,-7.92273803883006 -136.759570035092,-7.91955468191544 -136.779948717057,-7.91631906382338 -136.800343696681,-7.91307441617318 -136.820735713962,-7.90982372683346 -136.841140145743,-7.90653940773665 -136.861510843585,-7.90330423127981 -136.881940180245,-7.90007855341495 -136.902301079399,-7.89680672993259 -136.922659000216,-7.89352889024075 -136.943094761522,-7.89025746962766
```

Comment: KML only has one CRS, so to go from one data format In NAD83 to KML, the software must do a reprojection.  GeoJSON the current standard, also has one CRS (the same one as KML), but the draft standard allowed others to be specified.  Probably the default behaviour for QGIS was to use the draft specification, so you would be able to create a NAD83 GeoJSON